# How to subscribe to STOMP messages from an application itself

Tags: spring, stomp, spring-websocket

Is there any way how to subscribe from a topic and forward messaged to another layer of an application (have a new Listener for given topic) using Spring?

Consider following message handler it handler which sends messages to a topic `topic/chat/{conversationId}`

```
public class ConversationController{

    @MessageMapping("/chat/{conversationId}")
    @SendTo("/topic/chat/{conversationId}")
    public ConversationMessage createMesage(
            @Payload CreateMessage message,
            @DestinationVariable String conversationId) {

        log.info("handleMessage {}", message);

        return conversationService.create( message );
    }

}
```

I would like to listen on this topic and do an action on some messages.

```
public class Bot{

    @SubscribeMapping("/topic/chat/{conversationId}")
    public void subscribeUserMessages(
            @Payload ConversationMessage message,
            @DestinationVariable String conversationId){


            // doesn't work 
    }
}
```

I've also tried use `SimpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(..)` but it doesn't work neither. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

My application doesn't use full flagged message broker, just the default one in memory broker.

Comment: can you clarify the question? what do you mean by "forward messaged to another layer of an application"?

Comment: I think he wants to intercept outgoing message and do something with it.

Comment: @Esala yes, thats correct. I would like to have "man in the middle"

Comment: You can do it with ChannelInterceptor. With overriding `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration)` you can set your own Interceptor. Extend `org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptorAdapter` and do everything you need.